# textarea con funcionalidades como adwords

Tags: javascript, php, css3

Como puedo obtener esta funcionalidad , de que el momento de poner una coma , resalte la palabra o palabras anteriores en el textarea.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es un área de texto, es algo mucho más complejo, generalmente por medio de una librería, por ejemplo [tagger](https://github.com/jcubic/tagger)

Comment: @Triby  Ok , muchas gracias